# update list status as per task status in php simplified the code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table task with taskstatus and table with liststatus, i want to update liststatus according to task status. if task status of all the users is 0 then update list status as 0 , if task status of all user is 1 then update list status as 1. below function update query is not working, please let me know why.

```
   public function setcompletedtask($taskid, $taskstatus)
    {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE task SET taskstatus = '$taskstatus' WHERE taskid = '$taskid'");
    $y = mysql_affected_rows();
    for($i=0;$i<$y ;$i++)
        {
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $taskidupdate = $result['taskid'];
        $resultselect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE taskid = '$taskidupdate'");
        //$no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultselect);
        //if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $resultselect = mysql_fetch_array($resultselect);
        $resultlistid = $resultselect['listid'];
        $resulttaskstatus = $resultselect['taskstatus'];
        $resultupdate = mysql_query("UPDATE list SET liststatus = '$resulttaskstatus' WHERE listid = '$resultlistid'");
        //$resultupdate = mysql_fetch_array($resultupdate);
        }
        if ($resultupdate){return true;} else {return false;}

    }
```

Comment: Please explain with an example

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an update query, how do you want to mysql_fetch it!!!?

Here is a note from php website:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

You should first SELECT all records that meet your condition, then UPDATE them based on their primary key field ...

Comment: No he's not fetching it. For every updated row, he's updating something else... **Update:** Oh yeah... He's updating!